# I'm getting java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError when I run my jUnit test on command line by gradle, but it runs fine when run on AndroidStudio

Tags: junit, android-studio, gradle, robolectric

So I finally managed to get my android studio to run JUnit test that's integrated with robolectric so I can do http calls and other things without running it on device or emulator. Followed the structure from here which worked wonders: https://github.com/robolectric/deckard-gradle

Now, I managed to run it fine on AndroidStudio, however I want to setup a cron so it can be run automatically, and when executing the test by command line via gradle I am getting "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no pjsua in java.library.path". Note that our code uses a pjsip lib code that we compile separately, and we put the .so file in the jniLibs folder. I have another jUnit test that's really simple, and that one works fine whether through gradle command line or AndroidStudio.

The gradle command I followed from http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support which are either:
1) ./gradlew test --continue
or
2) ./gradlew test -Dtest.single=Test.java

This is what our gradle file looks like for the app layer:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {  
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.foo.test"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 21
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    ndk {
        moduleName "libpjsua"
    }
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        jni.srcDirs = []
    }
}

signingConfigs {
// hidden
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
    debug {
    }
}
}

dependencies {  
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')  
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'  
    compile files('libs/android-logging-log4j-1.0.3.jar')  
    compile files('libs/libphonenumber-6.2.jar')  
    compile files('libs/log4j-1.2.17.jar')  
    compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')  
    compile files('libs/ostermillerutils_1_07_00.jar')  

// dependencies to do automation testing
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1'
testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.1'
testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.1'
testCompile('org.robolectric:robolectric:2.4') {
    exclude module: 'classworlds'
    exclude module: 'commons-logging'
    exclude module: 'httpclient'
    exclude module: 'maven-artifact'
    exclude module: 'maven-artifact-manager'
    exclude module: 'maven-error-diagnostics'
    exclude module: 'maven-model'
    exclude module: 'maven-project'
    exclude module: 'maven-settings'
    exclude module: 'plexus-container-default'
    exclude module: 'plexus-interpolation'
    exclude module: 'plexus-utils'
    exclude module: 'wagon-file'
    exclude module: 'wagon-http-lightweight'
    exclude module: 'wagon-provider-api'
}
}
```

Does anyone have any idea? Many thanks in advance, been at this for a couple of days now.

Comment: I've got a similar problem here.